# installing android apps from pc/web

Tags: android, google-play, adb, sideloading

I know installing an app thro other places like pc/web is possible , Sideloading android From Your PC or possible through manual login into google play and installing.

Is there a way to achieve the same through code/google play APIs? I dont want to use adb or unknown sources.

E.g I want to install/push watsapp thro code from my pc/web

Comment: So you want to install an app from an unknown source on to a user's device without first making the user enable installation from unknown sources? Sounds fishy.

Comment: No, you can't -- the idea behind the "unknown sources" setting is to prevent exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: i think i have mentioned clearly. its not a unknown source. its a app from google play store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's possible, but not officially.

You can login to the google play website from code and simulate a button click there. [This](https://github.com/virifi/PlayAppInstaller) is a sample application doing exactly that, including login via device's google account. I don't know if it's still working, cause it's build against the old google play website, but I assume the source code could be helpful anyways (documentation is in japanese, use google translate for that).

Comment: is it possible to do it from a PC? detecting the google play login from desktop app?

Comment: You can use the [google-api-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) to login but you would need the users login data. After retrieving the auth token, the procedure will be kind of the same as on android.

Comment: is there any google api to trigger google-play install

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the 'install from unknown sources' selected on the client device, you will NOT be able to sideload apps to a device under any circumstances.

Otherwise if this is enabled, there are very few restrictions on how to do this (pretty much any way you can copy an APK file onto a device will allow it to be installed).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new [Android emulator for pc](http://www.andyroid.net) called andyroid - www.andyroid.net that allows you to run any google play app directly from your desktop

Comment: Can it be used for development? I can't seem to get adb to see it.